# How I can give an existing role to a user with mention?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want give an existing role to a user. I tried with this code but it's not working:

```
@client.command()
async def give(ctx, member: discord.User):
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="admin")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

I'm trying to make a command to give the admin role to a user.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? What do you mean it's not working? Is there an error, or is it just silently failing to add the admin role to  the user?

Comment: I'm getting this error : member is a required argument that is missing. when i try use !give @user

Answer (score 1):

First, you must add '*' between ctx and member. You must then reference the server instance in the role variable. This should be 'ctx.server'. Apart from that it should work. Just a tip for future reference; don't name your discord.User instance as member, since it can be a bit confusing. This should be it, if there are any more issues, please contact me.